# Import Icomoon in Custom Template

Tags: templates, joomla, icons, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla 3.2 and I'am building a custom template.. I've seen that the default joomla template (protostar) is using icomoon but it has over 700 lines of code inside the template.css for each icon.. example:

```
.icon-credit:before {
    content: "\e286";
}
```

I would like to use them in my template, is there any better way to load them ?

Comment: Why not just use icomoon application to generate you own icon set, with only the icons you require?

Comment: I will try but it looks like that few icons which are included in the joomla package are missing from the application.. ex: icon-chevron-right
Anyway thank you for your suggestion.